# Skip some rows from html result in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a website in laravel.

I am using =>

Laravel version: 5.7

Xampp version: xampp-win32-7.2.8-0-VC15-installer.exe

Bootstrap version: 4.1.3

jquery version:  3.3.1

PHP version: 7.2.8

When refreshing website some rows skipped. Sometimes it is works correctly, but sometimes skipped some rows and HTML tags were broken.

For example:

blade.php:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mt-3">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @forelse($bestPosts as $bestPost)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $bestPost->title }}</td>
                <td>{{ date('d.m.Y', strtotime($bestPost->datetime)) }}</td>
                <td>{{ $bestPost->hits }}</td>
            </tr>
        @empty
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="text-center bg-warning">No post</td>
            </tr>
        @endforelse
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mt-3">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @forelse($newVisitors as $newVisitor)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="/flags/{{ $newVisitor->country_code3 }}.png" alt="{{ $newVisitor->country_code3 }}" class="border mr-1">
                    {{ $newVisitor->country_code3 }}
                </td>
                <td>{{ $newVisitor->year }}</td>
                <td>{{ $newVisitor->month }}</td>
                <td>{{ $newVisitor->count }}</td>
            </tr>
        @empty
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="text-center bg-warning">No visitor</td>
            </tr>
        @endforelse
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

output HTML :

[image: img]

Ho can I solve this problem

Sometimes when refresh red lines are skipped

Comment: "Sometimes it is works correctly, but sometimes skipped some rows"  - is that with the exact same input data and same browser?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `<` at row

```
                    img src="/flags/{{ $newVisitor->country_code3 }}.png" alt="{{ $newVisitor->country_code3 }}" class="border mr-1">
```

Comment: Sorry I forget this when I paste to question

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mt-3">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @if(count($bestPosts)>0)
        @foreach($bestPosts as $bestPost)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $bestPost->title }}</td>
                <td>{{ date('d.m.Y', strtotime($bestPost->datetime)) }}</td>
                <td>{{ $bestPost->hits }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        @else
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="text-center bg-warning">No post</td>
            </tr>
        @endif
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mt-3">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Month</th>
            <th>Count</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @if(count($newVisitors)>0)
        @foreach($newVisitors as $newVisitor)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{ '/flags/'.$newVisitor->country_code3 }}.png" alt="{{ $newVisitor->country_code3 }}" class="border mr-1" />
                    {{ $newVisitor->country_code3 }}
                </td>
                <td>{{ $newVisitor->year }}</td>
                <td>{{ $newVisitor->month }}</td>
                <td>{{ $newVisitor->count }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        @else
         <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="text-center bg-warning">No visitor</td>
        </tr>
        @endif
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What difference between using only forelse or using if with foreach ?

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: i think your data is not giving proper output , try to print json response and check your data once

Comment: I try print json but not helps. I think problem was in php

Comment: try to `print_r($bestPosts)` and `print_r($newVisitors)`